# Python regex matching multiple words from a list

Tags: python, regex

I have a list of words and a string and would like to get back a list of words from the original list which are found in the string.

Ex:

```
import re

lof_terms = ['car', 'car manufacturer', 'popular']
str_content = 'This is a very popular car manufacturer.'

pattern = re.compile(r"(?=(\b" + r"\b|".join(map(re.escape, lof_terms)) + r"\b))")
found_terms = re.findall(pattern, str_content)
```

This will only return ['car', 'popular']. It fails to catch 'car manufacturer'. However it will catch it if I change the source list of terms to
`lof_terms = ['car manufacturer', 'popular']`

Somehow the overlapping between 'car' and 'car manufacturer' seems to be source of this issue.

Any ideas how to get over this?

Many thanks

Comment: is `regex` must?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current code can be fixed if you first sort the `lof_terms` by length in the descending order:

```py
rx = r"(?=\b({})\b)".format("|".join(map(re.escape, sorted(lof_terms, key=len, reverse=True))))
pattern = re.compile(rx)
```

Note that in this case, `\b` word boundaries are only used once on either end of the grouping, no need to repeat them around each alternative. See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/PRmUro/1/).

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/xpSp1D):

```py
import re

lof_terms = ['car', 'car manufacturer', 'popular']
str_content = 'This is a very popular car manufacturer.'

rx = r"(?=\b({})\b)".format("|".join(map(re.escape, sorted(lof_terms, key=len, reverse=True))))
pattern = re.compile(rx)
found_terms = re.findall(pattern, str_content)
print(found_terms)
# => ['popular', 'car manufacturer']
```

Comment: I've implemented your solution and it indeed does the job.
Thank you very much for you help.